# Talend freeze - Can some config suggestions help avoid freeze?

Tags: talend

My Talend ESB (6.1.1_20151214_1327) keeps freezing ... run freeze .. resize a tab freeze .. move to another tab and come back freeze ..

So I thought there must be some problem with my windows7, so I tried in my mac laptop, exactly the same thing keeps happening. Same for 610 ESB, Same for DI version too.

Is there an option that I need to change in config to avoid that? Waiting for 10min for defreeze, or at times rebooting makes me scared of creating more artifacts in Talend (I only have 3 now). I wish not to move to python.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am having the same problem with Talend Studio 6.5.1

Comment: I was exploring possibility of using TESB. However, with the frequent-freeze, and inability to  get SoapConsumer to work with a nonstandard HPNonstop-webservice (SoapUI is able to call), I figured it is easier to create a java client - DONE.  TESB forum is not responsive  Abandon.

Answer (score 1):

If you output a lot of data to the console using a tLogRow component, you will find that your Talend Studio will freeze, especially when changing tabs etc.

Try removing any tLogRows that you have and see if the avoids the freeze.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround on Two points about talend freeze.

that is

**pt 1:**
Please check if there are spaces in the path of product installation and the workspace, if so, try to install it without spaces in the path.
Talend recommend user to use 7-zip to unzip the products.

**pt 2:**
Based on source 
"https://help.talend.com/display/TalendESBHandsonGuide60EN/4.5+Accessing+all+ESB+event+logs+in+Talend+Administration+Center"
We can capture exact error.and then ,work on it accordingly.

or

It is possible that
To launch product,Sometimes we may launch wrong exe for our environment.
Follow this guide
"https://help.talend.com/display/TalendESBInstallationGuide60EN/3.5.1+Installing+the+Talend+Studio"

Comment: Pt1: No spaces in path mac/win7.  Pt2b: x86_64.exe / -cocoa.app. Will check Pt2a.

Comment: These links are broken.